# Deriving right relation from collected data.

Tags: algorithms

This is an elaborate version of a question i asked earlier. Lets say I have a data set from a user, which is logs of event occurred.

```
2013-10-09 => 01:34:45, 01:45:12, 02:38:23, 06:56:34, 13:34:45, 14:12:34
2013-10-10 => 01:36:12, 02:23:43, 02:55:11, 03:23:21, 04:33:11, 11:33:54, 13:23:21, 15:22:32, 15:23:12
```

You can see that there are total 6 events on 10-09 and 9 events on 10-10

Now based on this data, I need to rate that user between 0 and 5.
According to our assumption lets say the normal behavior is 5 events per day each at an interval of at least 20 minutes.

What i have done so far is try to derive an expression based on proportionality.

If $r$ is rate, $i$ is the mean interval between events in $x$ days. $n$ is the number of events:

$r \alpha i $ and $r \alpha \frac 1 n $

So, $ r = k \frac i n $ , where k is proportionality constant.
Now as per observaion and assumptions, if mean interval is 20 minutes (1200 seconds ) and number of event is 5, $r$ is 5.

So $ k = r \frac ni = 0.02$

Finally we have, $r = 0.02 \frac i n$

Am I on the right path, deriving this expression? Do you see any errors or anything I might have missed or can do to better determine the rates?

The main thing here is, a user can report false event as for each event, the user earns a reward point. Now what we are trying to do is to determine whether the user is tampering with the data and that the events reported are authentic.

Comment: You need to define the meaning of your rating: what kind of measure is it? Let's say, you have a user with just two events, one before 1am and another one after 11pm. The rating will approximate to 0.02 x 23 hr / 2 = 0.02 x 82800 sec / 2 = 828. Leave alone the fact for a while it's exceedingly large, however it's kind of bad as user is far from expected. OTOH, another user generates a lots of events evenly, effectively putting r close to 0. Far from ideal again, so r is just not representative at all. Define how you want to change r if user deviates from ideal to either direction?

Comment: $r$ is actually a measure of the validity of the events reported by the user (software). If interval is very low then its safe to say that the user is tampering with the software, but if the interval is really high, that would just mean that the user is not active enough, and the rating should be an acceptable number.

Comment: So, you're just not interested to track users producing low volume of events, right? What about the dependency of rating from events frequency IF all of them spread on ideal interval of 20mins? Say, compare a user producing all possible 72 events with exact 20mins distances with "fully ideal" user being active only just about 1.5hr (80 mins = 4 intervals x 20min) and producing opnly 5 events? Assuming second user getting $r=5$, then what $r$ will be for the 1st more frequent user?

Comment: Right now all I am trying to find is the authenticity of the events reported. Low event frequency might help determine the quality/performance of the user, which actually is in my tasklist :). But for now low event frequency will mean that the event reports are authentic.